# Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

If we have an algorithm which is order `N^2*logN`, and if it takes 1 ms with input size 64; does it take 2^10*(11/6) ms to run this algorithm with input size 2048? I am using direct proportion here, that's why it seemed defective to me.

Comment: Have you tried running the algorithm with a 2048-sized input set? How long did it take?

Comment: These numbers are so small that there's a non-negligible probability that lower-order terms still have a significant impact.

Comment: Actually this is for time complexity issue on paper, I haven't tried writing an algorithm whose order is N^2*logN and tried inputs.

Comment: Not necessarily. Time complexity is usually presented in asymptotic notation and only tells you about the limiting behavior as the inputs grow very large. It is not meant to tell you anything about "small" inputs or fixed (constant size) or lower order costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to solve is probably to divide 2048 by 64, plug the resulting number into the complexity equation, and the result is the number of milliseconds for Input size 2048.

Comment: It sounds very reasonable, so answer is if f(x)=x^2*logx, then f(2^11/2^6) = f(2^5), right?

Comment: This is not typically how time complexity is presented / works. `O(N^2 * log(N))` may mean for example that the algorithm takes `15 N^2 * log(27 N) + 573 N + 10000000000` steps for inputs of size `N`.

Comment: If lower ordered terms are ignored? Is it this way then right? Because I wrote some simple program with 3 nested loops doing nothing, and they obeyed the rule Robert explained.

Comment: Your simple program was probably exactly `N^3`, for example, so scales exactly like `N^3`. You would say it is `O(N^3)`. However, a program that takes `10 * N^3 + 100 * N^2 + 1000 * N + 10000` steps would also be called `O(N^3)` but would not scale exactly like `N^3`. It would scale on the _order_ of `N^3` for _large_ `N`, and to the constant multiple `10` attached to `N^3`, which is also ignored in Big-O notation. For smaller `N`, the other terms are much more important, and the scaling won't be obvious.